# Tourist utopian island where you could only stay 6 days as something horrible happens on the 7th

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I remember reading, recently (2018 or so) a short sci-fi/horror story online about a tourist visiting a utopian island, the catch was that a tourist could only stay six days, as something horrible would occur on the 7th of each week, as the price for this utopia's existence.

While there, there were 6 days of carnivals and festivals, while I seem to recall that those who lived through the 7th day were immortal, or that you didn't age on the island?

The main character (male) had met a girl while visiting, and decided to abandon his ticket back to the mainland.

There was a particular scene I recall at the striking of midnight of the 7th day, the man and this woman were in a club when things start to go awry, teeth cracking and blood pooling on the floor.

After the 7th day everyone recovers however, and the cycle begins again, no one discusses or even acknowledged the previous day, as a mutual agreement.

Some of the scenes from the 7th day I believe talk of radio chatter and modern weaponry, so the book is from the late 20th century I would imagine.

Comment: Probably not the book you're looking for but I seem to remember something similar also happens in Jack Vance's "To Live Forever". Not one of his best books though.

Comment: [_Thirteen Days by Sunset Beach_](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27272975-thirteen-days-by-sunset-beach) would seem to match somewhat but I'm only going by reviews so can't say for sure.

Comment: @David, that's the one! I thought it was an odd one for me to have read myself, and that it might have been through here that I found it originally, but I couldn't find the post. 10 days, not 7, looks like I was right about the rather grim teeth part, just not quite the context of it.

Comment: @David This question has no accepted answer, in any form, and so it is not a duplicate. (Normally anyway, here the OP confirmed it because of the dupe vote but normally don't vote to close until the OP has confirmed).